# What are Dirac spinors and why did relativistic quantum mechanics need them?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

I have a good grasp of the Schrödinger equation and the basics of special relativity But the Dirac equation is alien to me. What are [Dirac spinors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor) and why did Dirac use them?

Comment: Are you aware of the original heuristic derivation of Dirac's equation by Dirac? It tries to find a linear equation for the relativistic relation between energy and momentum. It finds that it needs to be written using higher dimensional objects. These objects turned out to be what we now call Dirac spinors.

Comment: More on [Dirac equation & matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dirac-equation+dirac-matrices).

Answer (score 13):

To understand what Dirac spinors are and why we need them,
you need to understand where the [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) comes from.

Dirac in 1928 derived a relativistic wave equation describing a particle
with mass $m$. The heuristic requirements for this equation were:

1. It should be a linear differential equation first-order in time
   *and space*. (This is unlike Schrödinger's non-relativistic wave
   equation which is first-order in time and second-order in space.
   And it is also unlike the relativistic [Klein-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation)
   which is second-order in time and space. However, the Klein-Gordon
   equation correctly describes spinless particles only, but
   fails for particles with spin, e.g. the electron. So it seemed,
   a radically new approach was needed.)
2. It should have plane wave solutions
   $$\psi(x)\propto e^{i(-Et+\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x})/\hbar}$$
   thus satisfying the Planck/Einstein relation $E=\hbar\omega$ and
   the de Broglie relation $\vec{p}=\hbar\vec{k}$.
3. It should reproduce the relativistic energy-momentum relation:
   $$\frac{E^2}{c^2}-\vec{p}^2=m^2c^2$$

Requirements 1 and 2 dictates the equation to have the form
$$i\hbar\sum_{\mu=0}^3 \gamma^\mu \frac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial x^\mu}
  = mc \psi(x) \tag{1}$$
with some still unknown constants $\gamma^0,\gamma^1, \gamma^2, \gamma^3$.
From requirement 3 these constants need to satisfy the condition
$$\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu=2\eta^{\mu\nu} \tag{2}$$
where $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is the [Minkowski metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Minkowski_metric)
(for details of this reasoning see for example at
[Three Derivations of the Dirac Equation](https://www.pas.rochester.edu/assets/pdf/undergraduate/three_derivations_of_the_dirac_equation.pdf), section 7).
Obviously this condition cannot be met with ordinary numbers. The most
simple solution to (2) is a set of $4\times 4$-matrices.
The solution is not unique. An example solution (known as the standard
representation of the [$\gamma$ matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices)) is this:
$$
\gamma^0=\begin{pmatrix}I & 0 \\ 0 & -I\end{pmatrix},\quad
\gamma^1=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sigma_x \\ -\sigma_x&0\end{pmatrix},\quad
\gamma^2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sigma_y \\ -\sigma_y&0\end{pmatrix},\quad
\gamma^3=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sigma_z \\ -\sigma_z&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $0$ and $I$ are the $2\times 2$ null matrix and unity matrix,
and $\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z$ are the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).
Then, in order for equation (1) to make sense, the wave function $\psi(x)$
needs to be a thing with $4$ complex components (which we call a Dirac
spinor).

---

But so far all this was just a speculative theory. The actual
confirmation of the Dirac equation came when its predictions were
compared to experimental reality.

- It predicted the electron to have spin $s=\frac{1}{2}$ and
  a [gyromagnetic ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio) of $g=2$. These facts were already known
  before, but lacked a theoretical explanation.
- It predicted [positrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron) (particles like electrons, but with
  opposite charge). Positrons were experimentally discovered a few
  years after the theoretical prediction.
- It correctly predicted the [fine-structure of the spectrum of the
  hydrogen atom.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure#The_hydrogen_atom) This fine-structure was already measured
  experimentally. But the Klein-Gordon equation gave a slightly wrong
  prediction about this.

Comment: " Three ways to derive the Dirac equation "section 7: Dirac was sitting in front of a fire when he was thinking about light and energy.In modern times without the fire would he have found the inspiration! Your post was very helpful .

Answer (score 3):

Thomas Fritsch's answer summarizes the history of the Dirac equation. Dirac did find it because he was looking for a first-order relativistic wave equation, which he believed was necessary for relativistic QM.

He was wrong, though. The correct formulation of relativistic quantum mechanics turned out to be quantum field theory, in which integer-spin particles are modeled by the scalar and vector field equations that Dirac believed were unusable. If there were no half-integer-spin particles in nature, we wouldn't need spinors for relativistic quantum theory.

Furthermore, no *Dirac* spinor fields are known to exist in nature. The spin-½ fields in the Standard Model are Weyl spinors.

The alleged predictions of the Dirac equation are a bit overblown. The Dirac equation certainly doesn't predict the electron to have spin ½, as Thomas Fritsch's answer states. The Dirac equation can model the behavior of any Dirac particles that may happen to exist, but doesn't predict that any do exist, much less that the one named "electron" has those properties. And, as I said, no fundamental Dirac particles are known to exist.

Dirac correctly predicted the positron, but his argument for it, involving the "Dirac sea", was wrong. The argument doesn't work for integer-spin fundamental particles, yet they also have antiparticles. (In fact, his argument taken at face value would imply that fundamental bosons can't exist at all—a possibility that I believe was taken seriously for a while in the early days of relativistic QM.)

The electron $g$-factor doesn't theoretically have to be $2$, although that is the simplest possibility, so it could be called a prediction in the sense of Occam's razor. I don't know much about this, but [Wikipedia has a short section on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio#Gyromagnetic_factor_not_as_a_consequence_of_relativity).

In summary, quantum field theory doesn't need Dirac spinors, and to a certain extent Dirac just got lucky.

Comment: "The correct formulation of relativistic quantum mechanics turned out to be quantum field theory, in which integer-spin particles are modeled by the scalar and vector field equations that Dirac believed were unusable." Could you help link to the explicit model equations used in QFT please? I have searched but not seen a direct concise single-page description of how many numbers are actually used in QFT vis-a-vis Dirac's 8 numbers, what are the exact evolution relations between the these QFT fields, etc? it would be beyond helpful to have a link to the final model parameters, thanks.

Comment: If you want parity conserved, you need pairs of Weyl spinors which combine to Dirac spinors, so for electromagnetism Dirac spinors are the most useful objects, whether you're dealing with a QFT or not.

Comment: @benrg (1 of 2) Can you please provide some general reference(s) to your statement that “The Dirac equation certainly doesn't predict the electron to have spin ½” and the Dirac equation’s predictions being “overblown”. Other than the rather dense reference traced via your Wiki link (Delgado Acosta et al. 2015 https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03640) I’ve been unable to find anything to support this view, which seems to contradict everything I’ve learned – but the upvotes to your answer suggest that physicists know more about this than a physical chemist has seen till now.

Comment: @benrg (2 of 2) And am I right to assume that the term “linear gauged Dirac Equation” in your Wiki link refers only to the fact that “The single symbolic equation thus unravels into four coupled linear first-order PDEs for the four quantities that make up the wave function.”? Answer – by yourself or another as well-informed - will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Others explained Dirac's motivation. One of the answers to your question "What are Dirac spinors" is they are a certain representation of the Lorentz group, i.e., they transform consistently under Lorentz transformations. This is one of the reasons of the success of the Dirac equation.